# IntelliJ IDEA: Exception removal will break source code. Proceed anyway?

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, refactoring

I have a method that throws a deprecated exception, which I've removed all cases where this exception is thrown. I tried to use IntelliJ IDEA's "Remove  from  throws list" refactor action to remove it, and got the following error,

[image: Refactoring]
[image: Error dialog]

What does it mean?

I searched for this on DuckDuckGo and Google, but the only relevant result I could find was [IntelliJ IDEA's source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-analysis-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/daemon/impl/quickfix/MethodThrowsFix.java).

Comment: Is this method from a parent class or interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the library you are using or how `ConditionParseException` is implemented. However, it seems to be a so called *checked exception*.

A checked exception cannot be ignored, you have to somehow handle the case of an exception being thrown. This can be done either by catching it or by delegating it up to the caller of the method. In your current implementation, the latter one is done by adding the exception type to the list of `throws`.

If you want to remove the exception from the `throws` declaration, you have to handle it using a `try-catch` block, e.g.:

```java
try {

} catch (ConditionParseException ex) {

}
```

Another possibility would be to make it an *unchecked exception*. For this, handling an exception it is not mandatory. For a detailed explanation of both kinds of exception, let me refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation).

**TL;DR**

However, if you want to completely get rid of the `ConditionParseException` type (since it is deprecated), you have to:

- click "yes" in the "Cannot perform refactoring" dialog
- remove every other use of `ConditionParseException`. (e.g. `catch` blocks and `throw new ConditionParseException` statements)
- remove the `ConditionParseException` java file.

Comment: I had already removed all cases where `ConditionParseException` was thrown. When I removed it manually, there were no errors. There were multiple types of checked exceptions being removed and multiple methods being refactored. Most of the time, the refactor worked successfully, but it failed twice. I was unsure what would it meant by breaking my source code.

Comment: The issue was that there was a couple places where these exceptions were being caught.